# Wormhole effect: warp space with opengl

Tags: opengl, glsl, webgl

I am looking for a way to do a wormhole effect like this:

[image: animation]
 - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WeOBXmLeJWo&feature=youtu.be&t=43s

I have already found nice tunnels in the examples, but here it is a little bit more involved. Actually the space appears to be warped somehow and the movement is high velocity, so it is not just entering into a simple tunnel. Any idea how to do the space warping part of it?

I decided to add more info because this was too broad:

I have a galaxy and each star has a 3d coord, size, etc. in this galaxy. I can visit these stars with a space ship. There are very distant stars and it would take a lot of time to get to them, that's why I need warp (faster than light) speed. This does not necessarily requires a wormhole according to physics, but this app does not have to be overly realistic. I don't want to solve this with pure OpenGL so ofc. we can use shaders. I'd like to warp the space in the middle of the screen when accelerating to warp speeds. After that a tunnel effect can come, because I think it would consume a lot of resources to update every star by very high speeds, so I'd like to update only the close stars. This can't be a prerendered animation, because the destination is not always certain, so this has sometimes exploration purposes and sometimes traveling purposes. I don't think warping only the sky box is enough, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: I don't see much warping unless you mean before they enter the tunnel. The tunnel itself just looks like a 3-4 layered tunnel (cylinder) with blurred cloud textures and a few particles.

You can warp things by rendering to a texture then and applying a post processing effect. [example](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/11/04/rain-water-effect-experiments/)

Comment: @gman Yes before entering the tunnel it appears to warp. Thanks!

Comment: you want to warp already rendered stuff or just skybox or everything during rendering? First of all you need to create a cone curves parametrized by curvature direction and position which you can animate latter. Static geometry will not do well for this

Comment: @Spektre I have a galaxy with distant stars and I'd like to add warp speed to be able to reach them. Sometimes it's just about exploring the galaxy, so it is not possible to solve this by playing the same animation every time I want to go to a different star. I think warping the skybox content is enough. Using a cone is a nice idea.

Comment: @inf3rno I would want try to answer but answer will differ a lot according that info I requested. You can distort geometry during rendering (3D vector), you can distort Skybox only (3D vector but objects stay unaffected), you can distort rendered scene in second pass (2D raster). So which one you want each has it cons&pros?  Also do you want pure OpenGL or can you use also GLSL and which version/profile ? BTW In what form is you stellar space stored (Raster Image, List of 3D star coords, ...)? Also I would want to code it but will have time for it maybe in the week end ...)

Comment: @Spektre It's complicated. The list of 3D coords is the closest, so I would stick with that. Thanks for your effort! :-)

Comment: Just to mention, warp speed or higher than light speed does not always mean a wormhole, it can be accomplished by warping the space behind and in front of the ship, but I was tired when I posted this question. :-)

Comment: @inf3rno added [edit1] to answer , sorry haven't as much time for this as I taught so just geometry for now. It is simple animated curved cone.

Comment: @Spektre No problem, it is more than I expected. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things going on there:

1. **space curvature around the hole**

   You need to construct equation that describe the curvature of space around hole parametrized by hole parameters `(mass,position,orientation)` and `time` so you can animate it. Then from this curvature you can compute relative displacement of pixel/voxel around it. I would start with cylindrical cones with radius modulated by `sin` of the distance from `hole` +/- some animation parameters (need experimentation).

   Something like this:

   [image: wormhole cone]

   and for example start with (in wormhole local coordinates **LCS**):

   ```
   r = R * sin(z*0.5*M_PI/wormhole_max_depth)
   ```

   Then modulate it by additional therms. The `wormhole_max_depth,R` should be functions of time even linear or with some periodic therm so it is pulsating a bit.

   The displacement can be done by simply computing distance of concerned point to cone surface and push it towards it the more the closer to the cone it is (inside cone voxels are considered below surface so apply max displacement strength)
2. **particle/light/matter bursting out of the hole**

   I would go for this only when **#1** is alredy done. It should be simple particle effect with some nice circular blended alpha texture animated on the surface of the cone from **#1**. I see it as few for loops with pseudo random displacement in position and speed ...

**Techniques**

This topic depends on how you want to do this. I see these possibilities:

1. **Distort geometry during rendering (3D vector)**

   So you can apply the cone displacement directly on rendered stuff. This would be best applicable in GLSL but the geometry rendered must have small enough primitives to make this work on vertex level ...
2. **Distort skybox/stars only (3D vector or 2D raster but objects stay unaffected)**

   So you apply the displacement on texture coordinates of skybox or directly on the star positions.
3. **Distort whole rendered scene in second pass (2D raster)**

   This need to use 2 pass rendering and in the second pass just wrap the texture coordinates near hole.

As you got different local stars in each sector I would use star background generated from star catalogue (list of all your stars) And apply the distortion on them directly in 3D vector space (so no skybox.. option **#2**). And also because my engines already use such representation and rendering for the same reasons.

**[Edit1] cone geometry**

I haven't much time for this recently until today so I did not make much of a progress. I decided to start with cone geometry so here it is:

```
class wormhole
    {
public:
    reper rep;          // coordinate system transform matrix
    double R0,R1,H,t;   // radiuses,depth

    wormhole(){ R0=10.0; R1=100.0; H=50.0; t=0.0; };
    wormhole(wormhole& a){ *this=a; };
    ~wormhole(){};
    wormhole* operator = (const wormhole *a) { *this=*a; return this; };
    /*wormhole* operator = (const wormhole &a) { ...copy... return this; };*/

    void ah2xyz(double *xyz,double a,double h) // compute cone position from parameters a=<0,2pi>, h=<0,1>
        {
        double r,tt;
        tt=t; if (t>0.5) tt=0.5; r=2.0*R0*tt;           // inner radius R0
        tt=t; if (t>1.0) tt=1.0; r+=(R1-r)*h*h*tt;      // outer radius R1
        xyz[0]=r*cos(a);
        xyz[1]=r*sin(a);
        xyz[2]=H*h*tt;
        rep.l2g(xyz,xyz);
        }
    void draw_cone()
        {
        int e;
        double a,h,da=pi2*0.04,p[3];
        glColor3f(0.2,0.2,0.2);
        for (h=0.0;h<=1.0;h+=0.1){ glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (e=1,a=0.0;e;a+=da) { if (a>=pi2) { e=0; a=0.0; } ah2xyz(p,a,h); glVertex3dv(p); } glEnd(); }
        for (e=1,a=0.0;e;a+=da){ glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP); for (h=0.0;h<=1.0;h+=0.1) { if (a>=pi2) { e=0; a=0.0; } ah2xyz(p,a,h); glVertex3dv(p); } glEnd(); }
        }
    } hole;
```

Where `rep` is my class for homogenous 4x4 transform matrix (remembering both direct and inverse matrices at the same time) function `l2g` just transforms from local coordinates to global. The cone parameters are:

- `R0` - inner cone radius when fully grown
- `R1` - outer cone radius when fully grown
- `H` - the height/depth of the cone when fully grown
- `t` - is animation parameter values `<0.0,1.0>` are the growth and values above `1.0` are reserved for wormhole fully grown animation

Here how it looks like:

[image: cone geometry]

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is simply calculate a vector from the texture coordinate of the screen center to the texture coordinate of the pixel you're shading.
Then modify that vector in any way you want (time based for example) and apply it to the texture coordinate of the pixel you're shading and then use the resulting coordinate to sample your texture.

In pseudocode this would be something like this:

```
vec2 vector_to_screen_center = vec2(0.5) - texture_coordinate;
texture_coordinate += vector_to_screen_center * sin(time) * 0.1; // Time based modulation of the vector.
gl_FragColor = texture2D(screen_texture, texture_coordinate);
```

Your question does not have a GLSL tag. If you plan to do this without shaders, this is going to be hard and/or inefficient.

Comment: Thanks, I added the tag.